# Using sed with parallel gives empty output when redirecting to file

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh, sed, gnu-parallel

I'm using the `zsh` shell. I am trying to use `sed` to substitute some text in many files, using parallel to speed up the process. When I tested this on one file and let the command output go to `stdout` I saw the expected result. When I tried to redirect that output to a file I got an empty file. What's going on? Here's a trivial example using a single made-up data file you can cut and paste to illustrate...

```
setopt interactivecomments
#  In this trivial example it is obviously non-sensical
#  to use parallel, but in reality I have many files...

#  Some very simple input data...
paste <(printf "%s\n" `seq 1 4`) <(printf "%s\n" `seq 1 4`) > ./input.txt
#  This looks like:
#1       1
#2       2
#3       3
#4       4


#  Pass data file to parallel and use sed to substitute.
#  e.g. want to replace line '3 3' with '3 33'
#  Output goes to stdout & seems correct...
z=`find ./input.txt`
echo "$z" | parallel 'sed "s/\(^3.*3\)/\13/"'
#1       1
#2       2
#3       33    ===> correct replacement
#4       4

# But redirecting to a file leads to empty file...
echo "$z" | parallel 'sed "s/\(^3.*3\)/\13/" > {//}/result.txt'

# Empty file
cat ./result.txt
```

What gives? Am I specifying something incorrectly?

I am using:

- `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS`
- `GNU parallel 20130522`
- `GNU sed version 4.2.1`
- `zsh 4.3.17`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using redirection inside the command for `parallel`, you have to use `{}` to put the input at the right place, as parameter for `sed`:

```
echo "$z" | parallel 'sed "s/\(^3.*3\)/\13/" {} > {//}/result.txt'
```

Additionally,  if `{//}` (or any other replacement string) is used, `parallel` does not append the input at the end of the command automatically.  (In this case that would be wrong anyways,  as it would be after the redirection. )

Essentially, the code in the question runs

```
sed "s/(^3.*3\)/\13/" > ./result.txt
```

but it needs to be

```
sed "s/(^3.*3\)/\13/" ./input.txt > ./result.txt
```

Comment: Not entirely correct: If any replacement string (e.g. {//}) is used, then {} will _not_ be appended. So the code runs: sed "s/(^3.*3\)/\13/" > ./result.txt (which is clearly also wrong. Use --dry-run to confirm). So Adaephon's answer is correct, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @OleTange Thanks for the heads-up. I edited the answer accordingly.